# Is it safe to buy a money market ETF that historically has large intra-day spikes when I can't set a limit order?

Tags: etf, money-market

I'm investing on InvestEngine which lets you buy ETFs at market rate, but there's no limit order functionality.

I'd like to buy a money market fund to try to get a better interest rate than banks will give me. InvestEngine has CSH2, the Lyxor smart overnight return which tracks the SONIA. Just when I was executing my buy order on InvestEngine, I got a bit spooked by the really large wicks on this ETF. This screenshot shows a typical example, a wick that extends 1.5% away from the "average price", by which I mean a trend line that joins the middles of the candles.

[image: CSH2, daily, since early 2023]

My question is, since there's no way to set a limit order with Invest Engine, what are the chances that my order fulfills significantly higher (or lower) than this "average price" trend line? If I got unlucky and paid 1.5% over the average this would wipe out any returns for half a year at the current interest rates.

Comment: Given that some of us don't especially believe in limit orders in the first place...

Comment: Those spikes tell me that the fund might not be that broadly traded.

Comment: There's no [volume](https://www.morningstar.co.uk/uk/etf/snapshot/snapshot.aspx?id=0P0001670S&InvestmentType=FE) to speak of (962 shares as of June 2nd)